# Parameter applicationName must conform to the pattern (Google Report API)

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-reporting-api

I neet to get the google hangouts meet data by java code and I am trying the google report api

the following is my code

```
String userKey = "all";
String applicationName = "meet";
String eventName = "call_ended";
Activities result = service.activities().list(userKey, applicationName).setEventName(eventName).setMaxResults(10).execute();
```

and the response is

Parameter applicationName must conform to the pattern (admin)|(calendar)|(drive)|(login)|(token)

the api I am trying is this, i can get the data in this link by the same parameters

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activities/list

and I also can get the data by the following java code

```
public static String getGraph() {
        String PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/activity/users/all/applications/meet?eventName=call_ended&maxResults=10&access_token=";
        String graph = "";
        try {
            URL urUserInfo = new URL(PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL + "access_token");
            HttpURLConnection connObtainUserInfo = (HttpURLConnection) urUserInfo.openConnection();
            if (connObtainUserInfo.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                StringBuilder sbLines = new StringBuilder("");

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(connObtainUserInfo.getInputStream(), "utf-8"));
                String strLine = "";
                while ((strLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sbLines.append(strLine);
                }
                graph = sbLines.toString();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return graph;
    }
```

I think it's not a good solution and what i got is a complex string

Any solution please!?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug already referenced on [Google Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker); you can check it [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154487570).

Answer (score 1):

Just use an old version of library `google-api-services-admin-reports`, I tested the following version:

```
  com.google.apis:google-api-services-admin-reports:reports_v1-rev83-1.25.0
```

My gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'SdkAdminQuickStart'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0'
    compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.23.0'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-admin-reports:reports_v1-rev83-1.25.0'
}
```